# How to get column names from a query in IBM db2 via SQL

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

Is it possible to get the list column names from a query in IBM db2?

Consider a very simple example I want the column names fetched by following SQL;

```
select * from db.t1,db.t2 where t1.id = t2.id
```

Actually I know how to get column names from a a single table. But facing difficulties to get column names from such scenario.

I want the list of columns as an Array in PHP. It can be done if I just add **"FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY"** as the end of the SQL, and run it. Then from result set I can get the columns.

But if there is no data then also I need the list of columns. How to achieve that?

Any help would be great for me.

Comment: You could perhaps make a separate query to get that info from the systable, Something like this: `SELECT NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TBNAME = 'Your-tabel';`. I haven'r tried it. Found it after 1 minute of Googling.

Comment: I know that.That is for a single table. What about if there is joining? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Try an `or`: `WHERE TBNAME = 'Your-tabel' OR TBNAME = 'Your-other-table'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`db2_num_fields()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-num-fields.php) to determine the number of columns in the result set, then loop over them and call [`db2_field_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-field-name.php) to obtain the names.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It should, as the result set metadata is created even for empty result sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do something like

describe select * from tablea, tableb